# Can't create OCR using this path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ocr

I am trying to use pytesseract for OCR:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd='C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img=cv2.imread('numbers.png')
```

after running the code I get this message:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:/Users/Mostafa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py'
```

These are the installed packages:
[image: installed packages]

Comment: Try using a raw string by simply placing the character 'r' before your open quotation on line 3, before the path. `path=r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with 'Program Files' because since there is a space in the middle that makes the program unhappy. Inserting a double quotes should be enough to make the program understand it should ignore that space in the middle. I Once had a problem with that and adding double quotes worked like a charm.

`"\Program Files"\`